# composing green screen video behind objects in 3d scene

Tags: compositing-nodes

[image]

please as you can see from the image, i want to compose myself behind the desk but the nodes available can only move the image in y-axis (vertical) and in x-axis (horizontal). There is no node to push the image backwards.
please if anyone has solution to this, i will very much appreciate to see it.

Comment: You need a mask. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117572/how-to-put-a-mask-into-3d-space/117941#117941

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3092/how-can-i-move-an-object-on-a-separate-layer-behind-another-in-the-compositor/3099#3099

Comment: Alternatively you can export the green screen element separately as an image sequence and use a plane with that image as a texture in the 3d space. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72053/how-to-add-green-screened-footage-to-this-scene/72056#72056