# Transparent Background for green screen clip

Tags: transparency, chromakey

I want to insert a clip (as an image plane) in my 3d environment. How can I make the green screen background transparent and save the clip with the transparent background. I want to use this clip in 3D environment.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39714/inserting-green-screen-footage-into-3d-space

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72053/how-to-add-green-screened-footage-to-this-scene

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114155/how-to-put-green-screen-video-on-a-plane-in-cycles

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45877/adding-multiple-green-screenplates-into-an-animated-3d-environment

Comment: [Compositing video layers in 3D space](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/compositing-video-layers-in-3d-space)