# Use images as planes with greenscreen

Tags: materials

I thought, that I would import "images as planes" a video of a green screen explosion and then remove the green background, but I couldn't find a tutorial for it. Any help?

Comment: Don't use images as planes, use the compositor.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/compositing-video-layers-in-3d-space